# Raphael display only selected portion of an image

Tags: raphael

I have an image as a background in Raphael.

I want to display only a portion of this image at any given time.

How do I do that?

Comment: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.image Have you tried that with different values of `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`?

Comment: Yes, and its always drawing the entire image, regardless of what I state. But what I want is, if I say 100 pixels, and the original image is 300 pixels, that it would then display just the first 100 pixels, instead of the image schrunk down to one third.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the clip-rect attribute to display only a select areas of the image like this

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 964, 641);
var background = paper.image("image.jpg",0,0,964,641);
background.attr({"clip-rect":"0,0,200,200"});
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NCncK/)

​